Order By of Long in JCR-SQL2
I want to achieve the proper sorting based on one of my property (orderByProp) in node.
Note: orderByProp is in Long datatype.
Sample:
Content Fragment 1 (orderByProp -> 1)
Content Fragment 2 (orderByPro -> 2)
Content Fragment 3 (orderByProp -> 3)
Content Fragment 4 (orderByProp -> 10)

I tried this sample query:
SELECT * FROM [SAMPLE] WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE ORDER BY orderByProp ASC

Result:
Content Fragment 1 (1) 
Content Fragment 4 (10)
Content Fragment 2 (2)
Content Fragment 3 (3)

It seems that the ORDER BY (Long) is not working properly.
